# jquery mouseout no works

Tags: jquery, mouseout

I have link for activate this little script when mouseover , the problem no hide when the mouse it´s out

**The Script :**

```
<script>

function show_subcats(id)
{

   jQuery(".cat_sub_menu_"+id).show(1000);

   jQuery(".cat_sub_menu_"+id).mouseout(function() {

   jQuery(".cat_sub_menu_"+id).hide(1000);

});

}
</script>
```

**The Link Activate the function :**

```
<div>
    <a href="#" onmouseover="show_subcats('1');">Menu 1</a>

<div class="cat_sub_menu_1" style="display:none;">
Content Sub Menu
</div>
</div>
```

When i go over the link show the div the problem it´s when i go out the link , no hide the div

I don´t know which it´s the problem

The best regards

Comment: Can you post some of the html that `$(".cat_sub_menu_"+id).show(1000)` refers to? Do these all have ids like `#cat_sub_menu_5` or something?

Comment: works for me here http://jsfiddle.net/b4ux4/ Remember you have mouseout on that `.cat_sub_menu_"+id` not `<a>`

Comment: Ok i put the code html

Comment: Yes works for show but must hide when mouseout in link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Check this Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4ux4/1/)

You need `mouseout` on link and use attached it to the `<div>`. That's where you went wrong.

```
function show_subcats(id) {

    jQuery(".cat_sub_menu_" + id).show(1000);
    jQuery('a').mouseout(function () {

        jQuery(".cat_sub_menu_" + id).hide(1000);

    });
}
```

---

The above solution, though it works, is not the correct way to define an event handler.

I would suggest this simple solution : **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b4ux4/2/)**

If you have multiple `<a>` links, choose the above solution.

```
jQuery('a').mouseover(function () {
    show_subcats('1');
}).mouseout(function(){
    hide_subcats('1');
});

function show_subcats(id) {
    jQuery(".cat_sub_menu_" + id).show(1000);
}

function hide_subcats(id) {
    jQuery(".cat_sub_menu_" + id).hide(1000);
}


<a href="#" >Menu 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will probably fix your problem:

```
<script>

function show_subcats(id)
{

    jQuery(".cat_sub_menu_"+id).show(1000);

    jQuery(document).bind('mouseleave',".cat_sub_menu_"+id,function() {

    jQuery(".cat_sub_menu_"+id).hide(1000);

});
}
</script>
```